# SupportFragmentManager doesn't see view id

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, supportfragmentmanager

I try to use SupportFragmentManager for my fragments but I get an error. Is it a glitch or something? It doesn't see placeholder id that is located in mainactivity layout.
R.id.placeHolder is red and it says unresolved reference placeHolder.

What can be a problem?

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
var counter: Int = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)


    binding.redBtn.setOnClickListener {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.placeHolder, FirstFragment())
            .commit()
        counter++
        binding.count.text = "$counter"
    }


}
```

}

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/placeHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: First check that you're importing the right `R` class, the one with your app's package.

Answer (score 0):

These `R` reference issues most of the time can be solved by checking if you imported the correct `R`, or `clean/rebuild/invalidate cache` actions, if none works, you can delete `.idea` and/or `.gradle` generated folders inside the project directory and `re-import` the project as a `gradle project` as a last resort